# how to implement pegman (street view icon) in leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

i would like to get street view icon (pegman of google map) in leaflet map. A pegman is a small icon in google map at the right corner. I would like to drag that icon on the map to get the street view..

```
var button = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" id="mymodal"  
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
  style="padding: 4px 6px;font-size: 10px;height:25px;color: #FFFFFF !important;">
  Street View</a>';

var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
        }
    };


$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('streetView'), panoramaOptions);
    });
```

this works i.e.street view icon is seen on click of button but i want on drag of pegman